# очень долго обрабатывает запрос mysql update

Tags: mysql

`update test2.c_s, test2.c_sub, test.c_sub`

`set test2.c_s.class_index = test.c_sub.class_id`

`where test2.c_s.char_obj_id = test.c_sub.charid`

`and test2.c_s.class_index = test.c_sub.class_index`

`and test2.c_sub.isBase != 1;`

`такой запрос работает если база маленькая, если база большая час пробовал ждать , безрезультатно, кто что посоветует?`
выдает ошибку
1062 - Duplicate entry '268482102-194-2' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Для анализа вопросов производительности нужна структура таблиц и индексов. Примерное количество записей в таблицах. Статистика по уникальным занчениям по ключам индексов. И самое главное, план выполнения запроса (получается командой explain)

Comment: может мне просто как то оптимизировать запрос? потомучто такой код делает за секунду
update test2.c_s, test2.c_sub
set test2.c_s.class_index = test2.c_sub.class_id 
where test2.c_s.char_obj_id = test2.c_sub.char_obj_id 
and test2.c_s.class_index = 0
and test2.c_sub.isBase = 1;
Query OK, 254898 rows affected
Rows matched: 259686  Changed: 254898  Warnings: 0

Comment: невозможно оптимизировать запрос, не поняв почему именно он тормозит. А понять это просто по тексту запроса нельзя. необходимо видеть план выполнения и структуру БД. Имея на руках эти данные можно оптимизировать практически все что угодно